# How to launch the web-browser of a mobile from Java ME?

Tags: java-me

How to detect from Java ME code that a `web-browser` application, like Opera Mini, is already installed in a phone? If so, how to launch it from Java ME code with a provided URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Midlet.platfomRequest method to [invoke certain applications](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-09E205E4-72D8-49A3-AF80-CA15804C9163.html).